# 404 image load issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to put a QR code in a website, arguably it could be any image file that is served from an ASP.NET MVC Action — but in this case its a QR code.

```
<div class="qrcodeview" >
    <h2>SCAN</h2>
    <img id="qr" src="{{qrlink}}" />
</div>
```

I am passing some querystring args to my endpoint to generate a QR code, which is returned as a GIF. Using AngularJS, I am setting the `<img/>` tags `src` attribute.

The url and querystring are being constructed within an AngularJS controller.

My issue is that before Angular loads and binds the data to the control, I am getting a HTTP 404 Error when the browser tries to fetch the image, before the Angular expression is replaced.

[image: Error message from Chrome Dev Tools Console]

Once the scripts have run the QR code displays, as expected.

Would prefer to not get this HTTP error. Can I defer the load somehow? Or use AngularJS slightly differently (more correctly?)

Thanks!

Comment: use ng-src instead of src

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `src` will cause a HTTP Request on initial load before AngularJS has had chance to update the attribute with the correct value.

Use `ng-src` instead so that AngularJS can create the `src` attribute when it's ready. This will then automatically fire off the HTTP Request to get the image.

```
<div class="qrcodeview" >
    <h2>SCAN</h2>
    <img id="qr" ng-src="{{qrlink}}" />
</div>
```

More information in the AngularJS documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc